# Reverse slider in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have to have a slider in shiny in such a way that it should have start value 100 and end value 0.

I am using the regular `sliderInput` function in this way:

```
sliderInput('Range', 'Range', min = 0, max = 100, post  = " %", step = 5, width = '100%', value = 10)
```

By using this function, I get a slider that starts from 0 and ends at 100 with an initial value 10.

But, I want the slider starting from 100 and ending at 0. (Exactly in the reverse order than the usual slider)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/sliderTextInput.html).

```r
library(shinyWidgets)
sliderTextInput(
  "Range",
  "Range",
  choices = seq(from = 100, to = 0, by = -5),
  selected = 10,
  width = "100%",
  post = " %"
)
```

You should create a new question for your second question.